# Вставка гугл карты на сайт и трансляция геолокации

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, вёрстка, google-maps

В процессе разработки веб-сайта для своего проекта столкнулся с такой задачей: нужно реализовать трансляцию геолокации курьера на мой сайт в реальном времени. То есть, нужно сделать так, чтоб на сайте на интерактивной карте все посетители сайта могли увидеть актуальное местоположение курьера. Пока нашел для себя три возможных варианта реализации:

1. Использовать функцию гугл-карт "Поделиться местоположением". Тут проблема в том, что на сайт карта добавляется без моего аккаунта и там отображать геолокацию поделившихся со мной через почту нельзя.
2. Каждую секунду(или каждые 5, 10, 20 секунд, там как будет удобно) получать координаты курьера и вставлять их как метку на карту с регулярным обновлением
3. Возможно, есть какое-то решение у самого гугла, которое позволяет выводить чужую геолокацию(на сайте developers.google.com не нашел какого-то решения)

Господа, прошу вашей помощи, так как впервые столкнулся с такой задачей. Знаете ли вы, как добавить на сайт карту с выполненным входом в мой аккаунт, чтоб отображалось метка того, кто поделился со мной локацией; если нет, возможно можете подсказать что-то по второму пункту(через JS, например). Или возможно? вы знаете какое-то иное решение этой задачи. Буду очень благодарен за ответ!